# How to deploy desktop application + DB (with server)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, sql-server-2012

So, what I have is:
 1. Created desktop application
 2. A lot of .dlls
3. Database created in MS SQL 2012
4. Crystal Reports (for clients)

Well, with all those things I am thinking about how to reploy all that into one .exe file so I can give it to my clients to install it easier then I would go to them, then copy all .dlls and .exe files I have, then install SQL Server and crystal reports. There must be easier way, like this one I want to make is.
I would like not to use some third-party installers for this, since I think that all can be done via VS 2012 deployment system.

Update: I haven't find any good solution on web for this, so I would like if some of you VS mags could help me to solve this problem, since this could reduce my instalation time a lot.

Comment: Well for starters you don't need to worry about the .dlls for your app or Crystal Reports, these should be included in the bin folder for your application. Secondly, you should have a script that should setup the database; the tables, functions, stored procs and so on. Then this script can be ran on the server.

Comment: Well that's something I do right now, but I would like to do that with only one .exe file so everything to be seted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that would suit your needs, this is free and easy to use. I personally use this to package my programs.

[Inno Installer](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: Actually this is very cool. Seems like it's really easy to use. I just have to find solution to add more things inside, but I guess there is a lot of documentation for this to use. If you have any tips&trick please share it with me.

Comment: They have great documentation and it's flexible. Remember if it's helped you don't forget to vote.

Comment: I will never forget to vote for article which helped me :) I just need to get as many info from you as I can :)

Comment: Thank You! There is much info for using this, I can setup an installer with this in about 5 min using the documentation. Good luck, if you run into problems let us know.